# How can I remove the Labels of the blue dots on the left plot and change the position of label nr16 in the right plot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, floats, labels

```
\documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.18}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[tb]{0.48\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=7cm, width=\linewidth, xlabel={}, ylabel={},  
ytick={0,500,...,1700},
    xtick={0,500,...,1700},
    ymin=-170,
    ymax=1700,
    xmin=-170,
    xmax=1700,
     ymajorgrids,
      xmajorgrids]
    \addplot[
        scatter/classes={0={blue}, 1={red}},
        scatter, mark=*, only marks, 
        scatter src=explicit symbolic,
        nodes near coords*={\Label},
        visualization depends on={value \thisrow{label} \as \Label} %<- added value
    ] table [meta=class] {
        x y class label
         0.3788 8.1653 0 -
 6.3716 4.0196 0 -
 0.4225 0.1447 0 -
 14.8118 6.6124 0 -
 2.7433 2.544 0 -
 152.0046 30.6336 1 5
 1375 428.5714 1 6
 20.51 5.1280 0 -
 38.8548 1492.8425 1 8
 0.1409 0.000196 0 -
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\label{}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[tb]{0.48\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=7cm, width=\linewidth, xlabel={}, ylabel={},  
ytick={0,2,...,10},
    xtick={0,5,...,20},
    ymin=-1.133,
    ymax=11.333,
    xmin=-2.266,
    xmax=22.666,
     ymajorgrids,
      xmajorgrids]
    \addplot[
        scatter/classes={0={blue}, 1={red}},
        scatter, mark=*, only marks, 
        scatter src=explicit symbolic,
 nodes near coords*={\Label},
visualization depends on={value \thisrow{label} \as \Label} %<- added value
   ] table [meta=class] {
        x y class label
         0.3788 8.1653 0 9
 6.3716 4.0196 0 10
 0.4225 0.1447 0 12
 14.8118 6.6124 0 13
 2.7433 2.544 0 14
 20.51 5.1280 0 15
 0.1409 0.000196 0 16
    };
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\label{}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

> Blockquote
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For everyone who is interested, I found the solution after reading through the package manual.
Although I don´t know how to turn the dots on the left back into red again.

```
documentclass[11pt]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[english,german]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext}
\usepackage{cuted, nccmath}



\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}



\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=1.18}

%\usepackage{pgfplots} %plots
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}



\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[tb]{0.48\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=7cm, width=\linewidth, xlabel={}, ylabel={},  
ytick={0,500,...,1700},
    xtick={0,500,...,1700},
    ymin=-170,
    ymax=1700,
    xmin=-170,
    xmax=1700,
     ymajorgrids,
      xmajorgrids]
   \addplot+ [
nodes near coords,
only marks,
coordinate style/.condition=
{\coordindex==6}{below},
coordinate style/.condition=
{x>0 && y>0}{black},
  coordinate style/.condition={\coordindex==0}{transparent},
          coordinate style/.condition={\coordindex==1}{transparent},
           coordinate style/.condition={\coordindex==2}{transparent},
            coordinate style/.condition={\coordindex==3}{transparent},
             coordinate style/.condition={\coordindex==4}{transparent},
              coordinate style/.condition={\coordindex==7}{transparent},
               coordinate style/.condition={\coordindex==9}{transparent},
point meta=explicit symbolic,
] table [meta=label] {
x y label
 0.3788 8.1653  .
 6.3716 4.0196  .
 0.4225 0.1447  .
 14.8118 6.6124  .
 2.7433 2.544 .
 152.0046 30.6336 5
 1375 428.5714 6
 20.51 5.1280 .
 38.8548 1492.8425 8
 0.1409 0.000196 .
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\label{}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[tb]{0.48\linewidth}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[height=7cm, width=\linewidth, xlabel={}, ylabel={},  
ytick={0,2,...,10},
    xtick={0,5,...,20},
    ymin=-1.133,
    ymax=11.333,
    xmin=-2.266,
    xmax=22.666,
     ymajorgrids,
      xmajorgrids]
 \addplot+ [
nodes near coords,
only marks,
coordinate style/.condition=
{\coordindex==6}{below},
coordinate style/.condition=
{x>0 && y>0}{black},
point meta=explicit symbolic,
] table [meta=label] {
x y label
 0.3788 8.1653  9
 6.3716 4.0196  10
 0.4225 0.1447  12
 14.8118 6.6124  13
 2.7433 2.544  14
 20.51 5.1280  15
 0.1409 0.000196  16
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{}
\label{}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]